# Elasticsearch using NEST - No Results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to do a simple search in Elasticsearch.

in marvel, I am getting the results back using the following query:

```
    GET /gl_search/poc/_search
{
  "query": {

    "term": {
      "Account_No": "056109"
    }
  }
}
```

The type is poc and index is gl_search.  See below

```
{
   "took": 28,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 23586,
      "max_score": 4.7722025,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "gl_search",
            "_type": "poc",
            "_id": "AU7fza_MU2-26YcvKIeM",


        var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
            node,
            defaultIndex: "gl_search"
        );
```

When using NEST, I am not getting any results back.  I tried the following:

```
        var r = client.Search<poc>(s => s
                    .From(0)
                    .Size(10)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .Term(p => p.Account_No, "056109")


            )
```

and

```
        var r = client.Search<poc>(query => query.Index("gl_search")
           .Type("poc")
           .From(0)
           .Size(100)
           .Filter(x => x.Term(p=> p.Journal_ID, "056109")));
```

Settings are:

```
        var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
            node,
            defaultIndex: "gl_search"
        );
```

**Update**

I dont see anything in Fiddler.  I assume I would see something there.  If so, is it the way I set it up or something kind of virus protection blocking it

Comment: how did you indexed the fields ?

Comment: before your `.From(0)` can you add `.Index("gl_search")` and try again and see if that helps? I remember weird stuff happening with `defaultIndex` (but that was ages ago and may be irrelevant) and for your `Filter`, it seems like you're querying `Journal_ID`. Was that a typo or was it intentional?

Comment: By default NEST camelcase field names. For p => p.Account_No, "account_No" will actualy be send to elasticsearch.

Comment: thanks guys for the responses.  

@Rob  I wanted to verify that.  But when I look at fiddler, I dont even see any requests.

Comment: @kha   I did it through nest, but lost the code that I did to index it. In the top case I did add the index.  and yes, there was a type with the journal id.  I was playing around with a lot of scenarios.  Still 0 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, NEST by default will camelcase .NET object property names when serializing the `SearchDescriptor<T>` into the query DSL. So, in your example above,

```
void Main()
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connection = new InMemoryConnection(settings);
    var client = new ElasticClient(connection: connection);

    var r = client.Search<poc>(s => s
                .Index("gl_search")
                .From(0)
                .Size(10)
                .Query(q => q
                   .Term(p => p.Account_No, "056109")
                )
            );
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(r.RequestInformation.Request));
}
```

produces the following query DSL (*notice the property is `account_No`*)

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "account_No": {
        "value": "056109"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, there are two real options for addressing this

1.Use a string for the property name, bypassing NEST's camelcasing convention but at the expense of not working with lambda expressions and all of the type safety that they provide

```
var r = client.Search<poc>(s => s
            .Index("gl_search")
            .From(0)
            .Size(10)
            .Query(q => q
               .Term("Account_No", "056109")
            )
        );
```

2.Change the default serialization options for NEST; useful if all of you properties are cased as per your examples

```
    // change the default camelcase property name serialization 
    // behaviour with .SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
        .SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer(s => s);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var r = client.Search<poc>(s => s
                .Index("gl_search")
                .From(0)
                .Size(10)
                .Query(q => q
                   .Term(p => p.Account_No, "056109")
                )
            );
```

A `Func<string, string>` is passed to `.SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer()` that will be called for each property that will be serialized to form the json query DSL that is sent to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks Russ.  Both 1 and 2 worked.  Thanks for your help

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)

Comment: Can i view the `DSL` query generated by `NEST` , I like to confirm weather i am querying correctly using `NEST`?

Comment: See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging.html